# Dell error code 0141 - No drive detected

Tags: hardware, dell, hard-drive

Has anyone seen the error code 0141 and it isn't a failed hard drive? I'm guessing the motor or board failed on the drive, but I'd prefer if there is a chance the motherboard or  controller failed instead. The reason I'm asking is because I don't have a usb/sata adapter and am curious if there's even a need to get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the error code, "drive not detected" could be a number of problems, including the controller.

You can try some troubleshooting by moving the drive to another controller/computer and seeing if it works. Or, put a known working drive in the failed system and see if it works.

If the drive doesn't work in another system (or a new drive works), you know it's the drive. If not, then bets should be on the controller or motherboard. This is, of course, assuming you have access to another system.

---

Also, have you tried reseating the drive and/or removing other drives (CD, floppy) attached?

Comment: It was the drive - the new one worked.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me after a bad firmware update of the hard drive. It basically means the computer, for whatever reason, is not getting an answer back from the hard drive. It is more than likely its the drive, or the drives controller, and not the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors:

I got the same error 3 days ago and the reason was that Windows 8.1 corrupted entire file system in my HDD in Dell Studio.

Condition:

1. Windows was not loading and computer kept restarting on boot.
2. Dell diagnostic clearly mentioned that HDD not found. Error: 0141

Resolution:

When I tried to use Ubuntu live DVD to see if other hardwares are working fine or not, I was able to see HDD partitions and all data in that so I formatted Windows partition with Fedora(because I was familiar with Fedora Linux installation) and then replaced Fedora with Windows 10 Tech Preview and it works like new. Now Dell diagnostic is also recognizing my laptop's HDD.

My suggestions:

1. Use any live Linux distro to boot your laptop and see if your HDD is available in that.
2. Otherwise use any Linux distro installation media and try to install it in your laptop. When the installer will ask for selection of partition or HDD then see if it has listed your HDD and partitions. Do not forget to delete and format existing Windows partition because until you format it you will keep getting errors.
3. Do not order new HDD without trying above suggestions because this way I saved my money, HDD and data all three. Installation of Fedora is easier than many other Linux distros.